# Post JSON data to Facebook

Tags: iphone, json, facebook

In the app, I want to post a photo, and some text. I am able to post if I am using local stored data in resources but when data (in JSON format) is coming from server at the run time, I am not able to post that image and text which is coming from server in the JSON format.

Is there any way to post data at the runtime or I have to store the data at the client side, but in that case, the app will be bulky because data could be different at different locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but you may be asking about posting an image using a URL instead of assuming data is local. If so, see this blog post - https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/526/ and it introduced the ability to post an image by passing in a "url" parameter through the Graph API.

Comment: No,Data is not locally stored,images are being parsed by JSON parser in the form of JSON from server and wants to post it on facebook.